# what will be the value of x? x= a++ + ++a + a++

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

What will the value of x in following line of code:-
x = a++ + ++a + a++
actually compiler is giving x = 3..but how????

Comment: What is `a`? Is there a value or just 0?

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior. Any answer is valid, up to and including crashing. It is unlikely that any particular answer will be consistent between platforms. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined behavior**, as the value of `a` is modified multiple time in the same statement.